# Network flow: the number of optimal augmenting paths

Tags: network-flow

I am confused about this:

> Show that a maximum flow in network G = (V,E) can always be found by a sequence of at most |E| augmenting paths.

What is the reason for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm equally confused about what you need. Please review  the [tour] page, and ask a specific question about what you're working on. (Doing part of the work, and then getting stuck, makes for a more answerable question.)

Comment: Actually, this is a question that as a practice problem for me for the midterm. To be honest, I am confused about it too. What I need is to prove the statement that: a maximum flow in network G = (V,E) can always be found by a sequence of at most |E| augmenting paths

Comment: Being confused is okay, but we can't answer without knowing what (specifically) you're confused about. As I said before, *doing part of the work (even if that work is wrong), and then getting stuck, makes for a more **answerable** question.* You're not doing yourself any favors by asking us to duplicate a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) page. (Even if that page doesn't tell you the answer, it can help you refine your question, which makes it easier for someone to know what you want.)